# Are there any randomized clinical trials being conducted on TMPRSS2 inhibitors for Covid-19 treatment?

Tags: covid-19, medications, sars-cov-2

In a recent [paper](https://journals.plos.org/plospathogens/article?id=10.1371/journal.ppat.1009212) on why hydroxychloroquine doesn't really work against Covid-19, it's been demonstrated that SARS-CoV-2 is much better at taking advantage of TMPRSS2 at the cell membrane surface, so that the cathepsin-mediated endosomal-entry pathway (which hydroxychloroquine inhibits) is basically irrelevant most of the time for SARS-CoV-2 infections in the cells it actually infects in humans.

There is one inhibitor of TMPRSS2 mentioned in that paper namely [camostat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camostat), but it seems it's only approved as a drug in Japan and for  other diseases: pancreatitis etc. Wikipedia does cite one small-scale retrospective [study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7671878) of camostat for Covid-19 (but actually conducted in Germany). That paper ends with the predictable suggestion that "Camostat mesylate thus warrants further evaluation within randomized clinical trials."

I also found an older (2017) [review](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7116903/#sec4title) on other TMPRSS2 inhibitors, but it's not exactly clear if any of the [other] compounds mentioned (aprotinin, nafamostat, AEBSF, leupeptin, bromhexine hydrochloride, and a few more which only have [long] chemical names) has been tested in any way against Covid-19, although some of these compounds were previously tested against influenzas. So, has any RCTs for a TMPRSS2 inhibitor been even started for Covid-19? Or is there some (other) reason to think such drugs would likely not be useful against Covid-19, so it makes no sense to test them?

Answer (score 1):

[Yes, there are a number of trials](https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?term=TMPRSS2&cond=Covid19).

16 of these studies are recruiting, [1 study started in April 2020, is  no longer recruiting and will finish in May 2021](https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT04321096?term=TMPRSS2&recrs=d&cond=Covid19&draw=2&rank=2) and no trials have been completed so far.

Comment: Based on those it seems camostat and nafamostat (roughly in that order) are the ones most investigated in western countries, with a multi-site trial in the US (and also a similar one in France and one in Germany) for camostat .

Comment: @Fizz Please go ahead and post a more elaborate answer using my links - I don't have enough time at my hands to do it more rigorously. (Maybe this answer should have been a comment, tbh)

Comment: If someone posts a more elaborate answer using your data, flag this answer for me and I'll convert it to a comment.